# Forward secrecy support?

Tags: ssl, openssl, cipher

Is it possible to amend the SSL ciphers to support forward secrecy on my CentOS server running Apache 2.4? I currently have the following cipher setup:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

This gives me an -A rating using the SSL Labs testing tool, but I receive the following warning:

> This server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference
>   browsers. Grade will be capped to B from March 2018.

This warning looks to be originating for IE6/XP. Is there any possible way to pass this rule with my server configuration? It probably isn't that important, but if there's an easy way to support IE6/XP devices easily - I may as well!

Comment: There's no reason to support IE6 anymore. It has virtually no traffic on the Internet anymore and hasn't for several years. Even the few people still running XP are using some other browser.

Comment: See also https://cipherli.st/

Comment: The cipherli.st link appears to be dead. archive.org says it was a redirect to [mozilla.org server side tls](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with IE6/XP. If you are still allowing SSLv3 or TLSv1.0 which is required to support IE6/XP, you are failing most test suites (including PCI compliance). Qualys has a page dedicated to their [SSL Labs scoring system](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide).

Regarding your ciphersuite string, adding !kRSA should do it. RSA key exchange does not provide forward secrecy.

I usually use the following.

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!eNULL:!aNULL:!kRSA:!SRP:!PSK:!DSS:@STRENGTH
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

Openssl documents the [cipher parameters](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1)) string.

Comment: Appending `!kRSA` to the end of my cipher worked. Many thanks!